# Where can I download the Learn to Play lessons in Garage Band 10.3.2 on Mojave?

Tags: garageband

I am using the latest version of garage band

[image]

I keep looking around the menu and online help, but I cannot find out a place to download the lessons.

Where can I download the lessons again?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I thought you could go to `File -> New` and then `Project Chooser -> Lesson Store`?  Have you tried that?